"OSError: [Errno 9] Bad file descriptor" on a basic f.close() (learning)
I was learning how to handle file in python, so i created a small code supposed to open a .txt file, edit it then read it.
For some reason, an exception is raised when I close the document between the editing and reading.
(I was following the first example of https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_file_write.asp, for what it's worth)
It's really the basics, but the other answer on this forum are for more elaborate project. I'll del if it's a duplicate
This was the code used :
f = open(r"C:\Users\Documents\blight.txt", "a")
f.write("suppress this later")
f.close()

f = open(r"C:\Users\Documents\blight.txt", "r")
print(f.read())

And the exception raised is :
[adress of the project]
OSError: [Errno 9] Bad file descriptor

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\PycharmProjects\Power4_00000\tester.py", line 3, in <module>
    f.close()
OSError: [Errno 9] Bad file descriptor

Process finished with exit code 1

Any lead on what I should change ?

Could it be the security settings, do you have permissions to access this directory?

I can open it manually so I assume i have the right. Plus it's a simple txt in document folder

I suspect you've only shown an isolated part of the code , show ALL the of the code. what has PyCharm got to do with this ....
